# How to find count differences for IDs in two large tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two large tables. Both containing around 17M rows each. They should have same exact number of rows but I am finding that the counts are different by 343. I want to find out where the counts are different. Tables look like this:

Table A

```
ID | color
---| ---------
1  | red
1  | green
1  | blue
2  | white
3  | black
3  | red
```

Tabls B

```
ID | sale_dates
---| ----------
1  | 2020-10-01
1  | 2020-01-10
2  | 2018-01-09
3  | 2017-08-08
```

Based on above I would like an output like below:

```
ID | Table A | Table B | Difference
---| --------| --------| ----------
1  | 5       | 2       | 3
2  | 1       | 1       | 0
3  | 2       | 1       | 1
```

Or even only find out the ones where the difference is not `0`

Comment: Do they always have exactly the same set of `ID` values?

Comment: yeah. they would have exactly the same value. In some cases there might be upper case or lower case mixed. so comparison should be uppercase

Answer (score 3):

If the two tables will always have the same set of `ID` values, you can just `JOIN` two derived tables of `COUNT(*)` values to get your desired output:

```
SELECT A.ID,
       "Table A",
       "Table B",
       "Table A" - "Table B" AS Difference
FROM (
  SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS "Table A"
  FROM A
  GROUP BY ID
) A
JOIN (
  SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS "Table B"
  FROM B
  GROUP BY ID
) B ON A.ID = B.ID
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Output:

```
id  Table A     Table B     difference
1   3           2           1
2   1           1           0
3   2           1           1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUgeN3UM9FJwxTgHgxaTir/0)

If you only want the `ID` values which have a non-zero difference, add

```
WHERE "Table A" - "Table B" > 0
```

before the `ORDER BY` clause.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUgeN3UM9FJwxTgHgxaTir/1)

Comment: And if you only want to see those rows where the difference is not 0, add `WHERE "Table A" - "Table B" > 0` before the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Timshel good point. I've modified the answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tweak on Nick's answer.  I think a `full join` is very important in this type of situation, because it is possible that some ids are missing from one table or the other:

```
SELECT ID, a.cnt, b.cnt,
       (COALESCE(a.cnt, 0) - COALESCE(b.cnt, 0)) as difference
FROM (SELECT UPPER(ID) as id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM A
      GROUP BY UPPER(ID)
     ) A FULL JOIN
     (SELECT UPPER(ID) as id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM B
      GROUP BY UPPER(ID)
     ) B 
     USING (ID)
ORDER BY difference DESC;
```

Add:

```
WHERE COALESCE(a.cnt, 0) <> COALESCE(b.cnt)
```

if you only want ids where the counts are not the same.

Comment: I did ask OP that in the comments and understood their response to mean that there were no `id` values that weren't in both tables. I originally wrote the answer as a full join but then changed it based on that... if I misinterpreted the response though this is definitely the right way to go.